# nested html5 draggable items

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, html5-draggable

I have a questions about html5 draggable items.
I've been looking at this example: https://codepen.io/retrofuturistic/pen/tlbHE

If I customize it and make the parents draggable

```
<ul>
    <li draggable="true" class="parent-li">
        <ul id="columns-1">
            <li class="column child-li" draggable="true"><header>A</header></li>
            <li class="column child-li" draggable="true"><header>B</header></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li draggable="true" class="parent-li">
        <ul id="columns-2" draggable="true">
            <li class="column child-li" draggable="true"><header>A</header></li>
            <li class="column child-li" draggable="true"><header>B</header></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

it turns out that when you are trying to sort a list-item "child-li" it tries to drag "parent-li"

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(dragSrcEl);
```

the dragSrcEl is the same as this.parentNode: the "parent-li".

So is it possible to sort the list-items as long as they're on the same level?

Answer (score 6):

It was late yesterday. I should use event.stopPropagation() to prevent bubbling up on parent elements.